How to find all prime numbers $p,q,r$ for equation $p^q +q^p=r$?
How do I find all prime numbers p,q,r for equation $p^q+q^p=r$. I know that one solution is $2,3,17$ or $3,2,17$ for $p,q,r$. I tried using Fermat's .theorem to solve this, but something is missing.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

At least one of the $p$ or $q$ must be equal to $2$, otherwise you are adding two odd numbers which can never be a prime number. That's a good way to start :-)
